# USB stick breaks the network access

Tags: networking, usb

Recently I've got a brand new Sandisk Extreme usb stick. It contains a NTFS file system and a encrypted NTFS folder that I can read/write on a Windows machine without issues. But when I plug it into my 14.04 LTS all the networking goes down, I can't access my LAN or the Internet. Everything comes up again automatically when I umount it.

Here's the syslog entries. I really don't know where to start debugging...

```
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.927433] usb 3-2: new SuperSpeed   USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro mtp-probe: checking bus 3, device 3:  "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-2"
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro mtp-probe: bus: 3, device: 3 was not an MTP device
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.943734] usb 3-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0781, idProduct=5580
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.943737] usb 3-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.943738] usb 3-2: Product: Extreme
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.943739] usb 3-2: Manufacturer: SanDisk
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.943740] usb 3-2: SerialNumber: AA011202140957272407
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.944109] usb-storage 3-2:1.0: USB  Mass Storage device detected
Apr 14 18:36:16 vostro kernel: [78283.944469] scsi5 : usb-storage 3-2:1.0
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.944624] scsi 5:0:0:0: Direct-  Access     SanDisk  Extreme          0001 PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.945402] sd 5:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.945480] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] 62533296 512-byte logical blocks: (32.0 GB/29.8 GiB)
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.945695] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.945704] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 53 00 00 08
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.945926] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.952456]  sdb: sdb1
Apr 14 18:36:17 vostro kernel: [78284.956342] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
Apr 14 18:36:18 vostro ntfs-3g[18907]: Version 2013.1.13AR.1 external FUSE 29
Apr 14 18:36:18 vostro ntfs-3g[18907]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 (Read-Write, label "luiz.kill", NTFS 3.1)
Apr 14 18:36:18 vostro ntfs-3g[18907]: Cmdline options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177
Apr 14 18:36:18 vostro ntfs-3g[18907]: Mount options: rw,nosuid,nodev,uhelper=udisks2,allow_other,nonempty,relatime,default_permissions,fsname=/dev/sdb1,blkdev,blksize=4096
Apr 14 18:36:18 vostro ntfs-3g[18907]: Global ownership and permissions enforced, configuration type 7
Apr 14 18:36:18 vostro udisksd[3748]: Mounted /dev/sdb1 at  /media/lzkill/luiz.kill on behalf of uid 1000
```

Comment: The logs don't seem to show much, but maybe you have a power supply or hardware issue. Is your networking connected to the same PCI or USB slot as your usb disk? Are you on a laptop, or a desktop?

Comment: I'm using the wifi of my laptop. At first my system didn't behave like this, it started when I reformatted the usb pen drive.

Comment: Have you tried restarting the network manager once you plug in the device ? `sudo service network-manager restart`.

Comment: I haven't... But even if it works I'd still need to know why this happens...